# How to read a .txt file from terminal, and then extract contents from file?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

I am wanting to use **C++** to extract the contents of a `.txt` file (that will be pointed to from the terminal) that is to be parsed, but I am not sure how to go about doing this? I know that we do

```
./a.out < file.txt
```

which will then put `file.txt` into the standard input, but then I got confused because I am not sure how to access the file contents to parse it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the directed input as input into cin. Say if I had the following file `input.txt`

```
Hello
World
```

And you run your executable like

`./a < input.txt`

I could do something like

```
std::string s1;
std::string s2;
std::cin >> s1;
std::cin >> s2;
std::cout << s1 << s2 << "\n";
```

Which would then print Hello Word. getline with cin is also an option here. Think of it as though a very fast user were inputting a line immediately at each of your input statements.

Comment: Thank you! This seems pretty feasible for a text file with just a few lines however. How can this be done for a .txt file with 100 or so lines?

Comment: Yep, this works on any input size. If you need to read from a really large file you can always use a while(cin) to keep reading from standard input until you reach the end of input.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename as input on the arguments to `main`, and open an `std::ifstream` to that file.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
    std::ifstream file(std::string(argv[1]));
    if (file.is_open()) {
        //read input
    }
}
```

You would call `./a filename`. To read from `file`, you would do so as you do from `std::cin` (see NickLamp's answer).